# How can I convert a decimal string value to int in java

Tags: java, string, kotlin, integer

I'm trying to convert a string "3.0" to int in java. I tried to convert using Integer.parseInt, but it throws an exception. Any idea how can I convert the string with decimal values to int in java and kotlin

```
String value = "3.0";
int i = Integer.parseInt(value);
```

Comment: parse it into a `Double`, and then do `.toInt()` on it. But you need to take into account what will happen with cases like `1.999` do you want `1` or `2` for that and etc. If you want `2` then that is a more complex thing, you could also try with `Float` instead of `Double`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In kotlin you can do this as

```
val str = "3.0"
val result = str.toDouble().toInt()
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert the string to an integer, then parse:

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(str.replaceAll("\\..*", ""));
```

This removes the dot and everything after it, which is effectively what casting a floating point type to integer does.

Answer (score 1):

```
String value = "3.0";
int i = (int) Float.parseFloat(value);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

You can't parse `"3.0"` as an integer, because it represents a floating-point value. Your best bet is to parse it as such using the handy build-in functions (`Double.parseDouble("3.0")` or `Float.parseFloat("3.0")`) and then convert *that* to an integer.

How you convert it depends on how you want to treat the decimal portion

- **discard it** (number moves closer to zero): cast to `int`

  `(int) 2.5` = `2`, `(int) -2.5` = `-2`
- **round it to the nearest integer**: `Math.round()`, then cast*

  `(int) Math.round(2.5)` = `3`, `(int) Math.round(-2.5)` = `-3`
- **round to the higher integer** (number moves towards positive infinity): `Math.ceil()` then cast

  `(int) Math.ceil(2.5)` = `3`, `(int) Math.ceil(-2.5)` = `2`
- **round to the lower integer** (number moves towards negative infinity):
  `Math.floor()` then cast

  `(int) Math.floor(2.5)` = `2`, `(int) Math.floor(-2.5)` = `-3`

**[`Math.round`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(float)) takes either a `float` or a `double`, and produces an `int` or a `long` respectively, so you don't need cast to `int` if you use a `float`. All the other `Math` methods take `double`s though, so I'm using that for consistency*

---

Kotlin is the same, the equivalents are:

- **parse**: `"2.5".toDouble()`
- **discard decimal**: `2.5.toInt()`
- **round to nearest**: `2.5.roundToInt()`
- **round to higher**: `ceil(2.5).toInt()`
- **round to lower**: `floor(2.5).toInt()`

(functions are in `kotlin.math`)